# How to use RequireJS for Yelp API, clientside javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, client-side, yelp

**I am trying to incorporate the yelp api into my web application. I would like the user to be able to make requests to the yelp servers without going through my server and adding additional data transmission.**

How do I require yelp and also call yelp.CreateClient with requireJS? Or am I on the wrong track?

The setup:
-lib

-node_modules

-public--javascripts---fileusingyelp.js

-public--javascripts---yelp library

-routes

-views

app.ks

package.json

---

[I am following this demo](https://github.com/olalonde/node-yelp/blob/master/demo/yelp.js). The code:

```
var yelp = require("../index").createClient({
  consumer_key: process.env.CONSUMER_KEY,
  consumer_secret: process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET,
  token: process.env.TOKEN,
  token_secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
  ssl: true
});


yelp.search({term: "food", location: "Montreal"}, function(error, data) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});
```

As I understand it, I can not use require in the normal way on the clientside. Because of this, I need to use the RequireJS library.

Here is my code:

```
var yelp = require(["javascripts/yelp/index"] , function(inp){
  yelp.createClient({//second error
  consumer_key: "key",
  consumer_secret: "secret",
  token: "token",
  token_secret: "token_secret",
  ssl: true
});
});


var yresponse = yelp.search({term: "food", location: "Montreal"}, function(error, data) {//first error is here
  console.log(error);
  console.log(data);
});
```

Here are the errors:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function coursecreation.js:12

Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined index.js:1

//this reference error is about the index.js file in the yelp library,

```
module.exports = require('./lib/yelp');
```

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function coursecreation.js:2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look at the [yelp library](https://github.com/olalonde/node-yelp/) you are trying to use. It is made for use with Node.js. In general you can't just take a library created *for* use with Node.js and load it with RequireJS. In the best case scenario, you can convert a code-base made for Node.js into something that RequireJS uses by wrapping the code with `define` calls.

Unfortunately, the best case scenario does not apply here because node-yelp actually uses some libraries specific to Node.js (for instance, [querystring](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)) and it calls on [node-oauth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) which itself uses libraries specific to Node.js (for instance, [crypto](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)). To be able to use node-yelp with RequireJS you'd have to modify node-yelp and maybe node-oauth to be able to operate without the libraries that are specific to Node.js. This is a major undertaking.

Note here that it is *possible* to design a library for use with RequireJS and use in Node.js. (I've done it.) It's just that node-yelp was not designed this way.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So if I would like to use the yelp library, i should just use it server side where I could require it(Im using nodejs)? Or could I do something where I copy the files in the library and use them somehow?

Comment: If you use it server-side with Node, what you need to do is use `npm install yelp` to install it (it will also install everything that node-yelp needs, including node-oauth) and then your own code can use it. You don't have to copy anything by hand.

Comment: Ah! So the reason I was trying to do it client side was because I was thinking it might be more data-efficient for my web-app users to not have to request the yelp results to the server, then get the response.  Server side it is! Thanks for the help, i was banging my head against the keyboard trying to get RequireJS to work :)

Comment: RequireJS **does** work with Node packages... http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Comment: @doublejosh What is it you are commenting on exactly?

Comment: I must have mis-read the post, I thought you'd said: "Note here that it is *not* possible to design a library..."